# Code for translating JSP to a class for portlet

Tags: jsp, compiler-construction, portlet

I know Apache translates JSP file in to Servelt (a java class) file. I would like to get the source code for this translator. I want to modify this to create a portlet class. I need to translate JSP in to a java class, where the java class generates code for a Portlet. I greatly appreciate, if any one can point out where I can find the open source code for this translator/converter. Once my translator is ready, I don't mind releasing as open source, if any one needs such converter.

Best Regards,
Raju

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Tomcat source code repository: http://tomcat.apache.org/svn.html

for example, here is the source code for jspc compiler:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/jasper/JspC.java

Now, just my opinion.

jsp pages cannot be converted to portlets directly, because portlets and jsp pages have different set of restrictions to operate with web-page structure.

but anyway - good luck with that :)